# How to set the value of the elements of the array to their position in the array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects such as:

`let array = [{ position:0 },{ position:1 },{ position:2 }]`

I wish that each object should store it's own position and update it when it's position is changed.

I'm using - array.splice(); to delete an object and then using this loop to calculate their positions again -

`for(let i = 0, length1 = array.length; i < length1; i++){ array[i].position=i; }`

But I want this to be done automatically without the loop
Is there any way to achieve this in js.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: You should add the code/function that you're using to alter the position of the elements.

Comment: @NinaScholz I've been using a loop to check it's position and  then assigning it to the position property in each object due to which I have to run the loop every time I make a change in the array.

Comment: @Andy I'm using  - `array.splice();`  to delete an object.
and then using this  loop to calculate their positions again -
`for(let i = 0, length1 = array.length; i < length1; i++){
 array[i].position=i;
}`    But I want this to be done automatically without the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ....and update it when it's position is changed

That's the tricky bit, you'd either need to wrap a Proxy around the array and update the positions when things change:

```js
let array = [{position: 0},{position: 1},{position: 2}];
function updateIndexes(array) {
    array.forEach((entry, index) => {
        entry.position = index;
    });
}
let parray = new Proxy(array, {
    defineProperty(target, key, descriptor) {
        const result = Reflect.defineProperty(target, key, descriptor);
        updateIndexes(target);
        return result;
    },
    set(target, key, value) {
        const result = Reflect.set(target, key, value);
        updateIndexes(target);
        return result;
    }
});

let second = parray[1];
console.log(second.position); // 1
parray.splice(0, 1);
console.log(second.position); // 0
```

...or make the `position` an accessor property that searches for the object in the array and returns its current position, which means creating the accessor where it closes over the array:

```js
let array = [
    {
        get position() {
            return array.indexOf(this);
        }
    },
    {
        get position() {
            return array.indexOf(this);
        }
    },
    {
        get position() {
            return array.indexOf(this);
        }
    }
];

let second = array[1];
console.log(second.position); // 1
array.splice(0, 1);
console.log(second.position); // 0
```

Comment: I am  sure this  will work, Thanks for the  answer.